# Remove ribbon for Anynonymous Users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I am looking for a way to remove SharePoint Ribbon for anonymous users. Most of the articles I have found talk about SecurityTrimmedControl which hides ribbon but doesnt remove ribbon or related scripts and CSS.

I am looking for a way to not to load Ribbon at all for Anonymous Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using client object model u can identify user using below code

```
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "SP.js");
 function getWebUserData() {
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();
this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(this._currentUser);
context.load(web, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),   
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {

   // Put your jquery logic for hide ribbon 
}

 function onfaiuremethod(sender, args) {
  alert('Anonymous User');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed JavaScript code ot master-page, that removes Ribbon.
Use Client Object Model to detect anonimous users.